# How to set worked precisely in IProgressMonitor in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, progressmonitor

The method `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor.worked(int)` receives integer which means increment. This means, that the only units available are natural units. It can't be percents, for example.

So, if I process some files in the job, I can't report the counting stage, because the first method I should call is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor.beginTask(String, int)` which requires me to know the total amount.

How to accomplish?

**UPDATE**

I wrote a wrapper below, but this looks absurd one need to do so:

```
public class ProgressMonitorDoubleWrapper implements IProgressMonitor {

    private IProgressMonitor delegate;
    private int currentWork, totalWork;
    private double currentWorkDouble;

    public ProgressMonitorDoubleWrapper(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        this.delegate = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void beginTask(String name, int totalWork) {
        beginTask(name, (double) totalWork); 
    }

    public void beginTask(String name, double totalWork) {
        this.totalWork = (int) totalWork;
        currentWork = 0;
        currentWorkDouble = 0;
        delegate.beginTask(name, this.totalWork);
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        delegate.done();
    }

    @Override
    public void internalWorked(double work) {
        delegate.internalWorked(work);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCanceled() {
        return delegate.isCanceled();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCanceled(boolean value) {
        delegate.setCanceled(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTaskName(String name) {
        delegate.setTaskName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void subTask(String name) {
        delegate.subTask(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void worked(int work) {
        worked((double)work);
    }

    public void worked(double work) {
        currentWorkDouble += work;
        int increment = (int)(currentWorkDouble - (double)currentWork);
        currentWork += increment;
        delegate.worked(increment);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a good solution for this, what you can do one of the following:

Do some sort of quick scan to work out the total if possible.

You can specify `IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN` as the value on `beginTask`, this gives you a different progress bar which just shows something is happening.

Just guess a value! Probably something that is bigger than the total worked value is likely to get.

If the work can be split in to several pieces use `SubProgressMonitor` for each piece and specify a reasonable work count for each part:

```
 monitor.beginTask("task", 2 * 1000);

 work1(new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1000));

 work2(new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1000));
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it better in Eclipse 4?

Comment: No change in Eclipse 4